# Dynamic Programming:Subset Logic

Tags: java

Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, beginning at the start index, such that the group sums to the given target? However, with the additional constraint that all 6's must be chosen.

groupSum6(0, [5, 6, 2], 8) → true

groupSum6(0, [5, 6, 2], 9) → false

groupSum6(0, [5, 6, 2], 7) → false

Just wanted to be clear on where I went wrong. Is declaring a special case for nums[start] == 6 the wrong approach?

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

 if (nums[start] >= nums.length) {return (target == 0);} 

 if (nums[start] == 6){ 
 return groupSum6(start++, nums, target - nums[start]);
 }

 if (groupSum6(start++, nums, target - nums[start])) {return true;}
 //if a particular number is choosen 

 if (groupSum6(start++, nums, target)) {return true;}
 //if that particular  number is not chosen

 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question: what will be the value of integer a in the method checkValue?

```
int a = 4;
checkValue(a++);
void method(int value){
    System.out.println(a);
}

public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

    if (start == nums.length) {return (target == 0);} //why did you compare some arbitrary number from array with length of this array? 

    if (nums[start] == 6){
        return groupSum6(start+1, nums, target - nums[start]);
    }

    if (groupSum6(start+1, nums, target - nums[start])) {return true;} //when you use start++ , you are calling the method with the same argument (i.e. start) recursively
    //if a particular number is choosen 

    if (groupSum6(start+1, nums, target)) {return true;}
    //if that particular  number is not chosen

    return false;
}
```

BTW. you can do it in fewer lines of code :

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

    if (start == nums.length) {return (target == 0);}

    else if (nums[start] == 6){
        return groupSum6(start+1, nums, target - nums[start]);
    }

    else return (groupSum6(start+1, nums, target - nums[start])) || (groupSum6(start+1, nums, target)) ;

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. apologies for the error, i mean to say "start" instead of nums[start].

Comment: a question: is there a difference between using start++ and start + 1?

Comment: You should not apologize, we are humans and we're making errors. It's normal.

Comment: a++ uses and then increments the variable..       ++a increments and then uses the variable, but the ++a is also not appropriate here, why? When you call method with (a+1) you don't change value a in

Comment: When you call method recursively with (a+1) you don't change value a in the current level of recursion, but in the next level of recursion value a will increment by 1 (i.e. a = a + 1)